# Disable a Plotly Dash component during callback execution, then re-enabling it after the callback has finished

Tags: python, user-interface, callback, plotly-dash

I have Plotly Dash components that need to be disabled after a callback has been triggered. The same components need to be enabled after the callback has finished running. I have tried the approach below. While the component gets disabled, it does not get enabled after finishing the callback function.

```py
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
from dash_extensions.enrich import (
    Output,
    DashProxy,
    html,
    Input,
    MultiplexerTransform,
)
from time import sleep

app = DashProxy(__name__, transforms=[MultiplexerTransform()])

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Button(id="button", children="input-button", style={"color": "#FF0000"}),
        html.Div(id="trigger", children=None, style={"display": "none"})
    ],
)

@app.callback(
    [
        Output("button", "disabled"),
        Output("button", "style"),
        Output("trigger", "children"),
    ],
    [
        Input("trigger", "children")
    ],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def enable_components_after_export(trigger):
    if trigger == 1:
        return [
            False, {"color": "#FF0000"}, 0
        ]

    raise PreventUpdate


@app.callback(
    [
        Output("button", "disabled"),
        Output("button", "style")
    ],
    [
        Input("button", "n_clicks"),
    ],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def disable_components_on_export_button_click(button):
    if (button is not None and button > 0):
        return [
            True, {"color": "#808080"}
        ]

    raise PreventUpdate

@app.callback(
    [
        Output("trigger", "children")
    ],
    [
        Input("button", "n_clicks"),
    ],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def callback_function(button):
    if button is not None and button > 0:
        sleep(5)
        return [1]
    
    raise PreventUpdate

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False)
```

What would be the correct method to disable components during callbacks, and then re-enabling them after finishing the callback? Also, I recall that Dash does not support multiple callback outputs, which is why DashProxy and MultiplexerTransform is used, though I am not sure if that is causing my problem.

Package versions

```
dash                      2.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi       
dash-bootstrap-components 1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi       
dash-core-components      2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi       
dash-extensions           0.1.11                   pypi_0    pypi       
dash-html-components      2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi       
dash-renderer             1.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if using `DashProxy` here is supposed to address the issue but anyway, since version 2.9 Dash allows [duplicate callback outputs](https://dash.plotly.com/duplicate-callback-outputs) : multiple callbacks can target the same output, the only thing would be to specify `allow_duplicate=True` in the callback outputs, eg.

```py
@app.callback(
    [
        Output("button", "disabled", allow_duplicate=True),
        Output("button", "style", allow_duplicate=True),
        Output("trigger", "children", allow_duplicate=True),
    ],
    [
        Input("trigger", "children")
    ],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
```

---

Note you could also achieve this using a simple [background callback](https://dash.plotly.com/background-callbacks) (ie. one callback instead of three).

> You can configure a callback to run in the background by setting
> `background=True` on the callback. Callbacks with `background=True`
> use a backend manager configured by you to run the callback logic. You can provide this manager instance to the `dash.Dash` app constructor as the `background_callback_manager` keyword argument, or as the `manager` argument to the `@dash.callback` decorator.

The idea is to use the `running` argument which allows to set component properties according to the callback status (ie. disable the button while the callback is running) :

```py
@app.callback(
    Output("trigger", "children"),
    Input("button", "n_clicks"),
    background=True,
    running=[
        (Output("button", "disabled"), True, False),
        (Output("button", "style"), {"color": "#808080"}, {"color": "#FF0000"}),
    ],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def callback_function(button):
    if button is not None and button > 0:
        time.sleep(5)
        return [1]
    
    raise PreventUpdate
```

Answer (score 0):

With Dash v2.9+ you can have multiple callbacks to target the same output. Here's a full working example of how you can disable the button after a callback function is triggered:

```py
from dash import Dash, html, Input, Output, no_update
from time import sleep

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Button(id="button", children="input-button", n_clicks=0, style={"color": "#FF0000"}),
        html.Div(id="trigger", children=None)
    ],
)

@app.callback(
    Output("button", "disabled", allow_duplicate=True),
    Input("button", "n_clicks"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def disable_btn(n):
    if n:
        return True
    return no_update


@app.callback(
    Output("trigger", "children"),
    Output("button", "disabled"),
    Input("button", "n_clicks"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_content(n):
    if n:
        sleep(5)
        return 1, False
    return no_update

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```